# GCP Pub/Sub idempotency key on Publish

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible for GCP Pub/Sub to respect a composite key as a sort of idempotency key to prevent duplicate messages from being queued on a topic when publishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, Cloud Pub/Sub does not support the notion of a key that can be used to dedupe messages on publish. There is [exactly-once delivery support on the subscribe side](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery) (currently in public preview), but that won't prevent redelivery if messages were duplicated on the publish side.

If you need to dedupe messages via a key used at publish time (likely an attribute on the message), then Dataflow [deduping is probably the best solution](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-cloud-dataflow-part-3-sources-and-sinks).

Comment: Gotcha - I was familiar with the Dataflow option to dedupe on the publishing side but it's quite a bit more involved than if an idempotency key were supported. Is this something that has been discussed? Hard to find conversation about this online.

Comment: Cloud Pub/Sub is certainly interested in the idempotency/exactly once space, though there are no concrete discussions or plans for publisher-side deduping that can be shared at this time.